# Is there a quick way to programatically scroll to top of scrollView? (Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, scrollview

Basically, I want the `scrollView` to get back to the very top after an `action` has been made, let's say after a button press. I have looked for a proper answer, but can only find solutions in other languages, including `objective-c`. Is there a method to call or do I have to program and call a custom code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scrollView.contentOffset = .zero
```

Comment: I did, but don't have enough reputation for it to actually show. Think it registers though :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set contentOffset to 0.

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```